# Override the save method to save it as base64 from Image field Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, base64

**models.py**

```
def upload_org_logo(instance, filename):
    ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
    filepath = f"org_logo/{ts}"
    if instance:
        filepath = f"org_logo/{instance.org_id}/{instance.org_name}"
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename.lower())
    return filepath

class Organisation(models.Model):
    """
    Organisation model
    """
    org_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    org_code = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    org_mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    org_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    org_address = models.JSONField(max_length=500, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='products')
    org_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_org_logo, default='blank.jpg', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    org_logo_b64 = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.org_logo:
            logo = open(self.org_logo.url, "rb")
            print(logo)
            self.org_logo_b64 = base64.b64encode(logo.read())
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I tried to Post, it is throwing me an error

```
FileNotFoundError at /admin/onboarding/organisation/7577ef5f-356c-4cbd-8ef6-e906382447ff/change/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/white-logo.png'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/onboarding/organisation/7577ef5f-356c-4cbd-8ef6-e906382447ff/change/
Django Version: 3.2.12
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/white-logo.png'
Exception Location: F:\PM-Onboarding-Service\Onboarding-Service\microservices\onboarding\models.py, line 244, in save
```

I tried the method based on this answer [django admin: save image like base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846390/django-admin-save-image-like-base64).

My **settings** for Media is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Can anyone please help me to save the image as base64 in the database by override the save method for the imagefield?

After update:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.org_logo:
            logo = self.org_logo.open()
            print(logo)
            self.org_logo_b64 = base64.b64encode(logo.read())
            super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Save method looks like this and When I add a Organisation with Logo it is getting Posted but in the org_logo_b64 column just it is showing as [binarydata] and not the binary value.

[image: Screenshot_of_DB]

And if I post without adding org_logo, it is throwing an error as"

```
ValueError at /admin/onboarding/organisation/add/
Cannot add "<Product: Project management>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/onboarding/organisation/add/
Django Version: 3.2.12
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot add "<Product: Project management>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
Exception Location: C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py, line 1055, in _get_target_ids
Python Executable:  C:\Users\gobs4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.4
Python Path:    
['F:\\PM-Onboarding-Service\\Onboarding-Service\\microservices',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\gobs4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 09 May 2022 12:15:28 +0530
```

Comment: Just call `self.org_logo.open()` to get the file pointer. The file may be an in memory file before the `save` method finishes running, which means it is not on the filesystem yet. Also the `url()` method is not the `path()` method of the file field, you are misusing that method.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat  I have updated my answer and error above, can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you can use post_save() signal for this, that way you are ensuring that file is uploaded correctly and then you can override the file content to base64 encodings in post_save() signal

Answer (score 1):

Both of the updated and original versions of the `save` method returns without saving in case of no `self.org_logo`:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.org_logo:
            logo = self.org_logo.open()
            print(logo)
            self.org_logo_b64 = base64.b64encode(logo.read())
            super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Try to add `return super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in the last line (which is actually an else case) or better just decrease the indent of the current last line to make it executed in both `if` and `else` cases:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.org_logo:
            logo = self.org_logo.open()
            print(logo)
            self.org_logo_b64 = base64.b64encode(logo.read())
        return super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It works thanks, One more doubt can I able to override the save method on the org_logo field itself. As I don't want a new field to be created for the org_logo binary. And I need to upload it as file object only and convert it in the backend and save it as binary in the same field. is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it will be overcomplicated to have FileField and BinaryField behaviour mixed at the same time. I recommend to encode/decode file in your view's serializer or form instead of model's save method. It will be more convenient.

Comment: can you please update the serializer or view based on the above scenario? I tried it before and ended up in this save method. It would be helpful if you help me with the code.